# JQuery Mobile - Loads wrong page after closing dialog and Javascript not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a project with two html pages (bmi.html and 7min.html) and some javascript... I use footer to navigate between the pages.

- 1st issue: first time run the 7min.html, navigates to bmi.html using footer and the javascript  in bmi doesn't work!
- 2nd issue: first time run the bmi.html, navigates to 7min.html and again back to bmi. Javascript works fine but after closing the popup dialog returns to 7min page.

Below is my code.

7min: http://jsfiddle.net/Rwf5G/
bmi: http://jsfiddle.net/snKyK/

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Body Trainer</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="7min-page" class="type-interior" >

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="appHeader" >
            <h1>Workout</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" >
            <h4>Brief</h4>
            <p>
                Some bla bla...
            </p>


        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-id="appFooter" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="bmi.html" data-prefetch="true">BMI</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="7min.html" data-prefetch="true" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">7min</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /footer -->

    </div>

</body>
```

(I am sorry that I use jsfiddle, I had some problems to add the code here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **First issue:**

   jQuery Mobile uses Ajax Navigation system to load pages and change views/pages. When you start with *bmi.html*, all HTML tags are loaded. When you navigate from *bmi.html* to *7min.html*, jQuery Mobile loads ONLY `<div data-role="page"></div>` and contents inside it. It neglects other HTML tags outside `data-role=page` div.

   - Solution: Place JS code inside `<div data-role="page"></div>`.
   - Option: To navigate without AJAX, add `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` to anchor tag. *Doing this, will load pages normally, however, you will lose page transition effect.*
2. **Second issue:**

   Add this attribute `data-history="false"` to `<div data-role="popup">` div.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! Just for the record I thought that the script code should be always in the head section...