# Preventing submit only works after refresh

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page which redirects to another page. On the second page, I prevent the .submit() from happening and do my own stuff. I did that by using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email</title>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/customtheme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#emailForm").submit(function() {
                    console.log("Submit prevented.");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST", 
                        url: "send.php",     
                        data: {
                            email: $("#email").val()
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                            window.location = obj.url;
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a class="ui-btn-left" href="index.html" data-icon="back">Terug</a>
                <h1><span></span></h1>
                <a class="ui-btn-right" href="#" data-icon="info">i & &euro;</a>
            </div>
                <div class="inform">
                    <form id="emailForm" action="send.php" method="POST">
                        <span>Email adress:</span>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input>
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I navigate to this `enteremail.html` page directly, everything works fine. My submit gets caught and the function starts instead of redirecting to `send.php` throught the form.

But when I start from `index.html`, which can navigate to this `enteremail.html`, JQuery apperantly already loaded the Ajax calls or something. Anyway, the function doesn't get loaded/called. I need to refresh the `enteremail.html` to get the function to work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: More specific: `preventDefault` doesn't work when navigating from page to page, but only on refresh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Mobile - Loads wrong page after closing dialog and Javascript not always working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269573/jquery-mobile-loads-wrong-page-after-closing-dialog-and-javascript-not-always)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the script from the `<head>` to `<body>`, specifically in `<div data-role="page">`. Then it works because the stuff in head is only loaded from the first time by Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

> **Default link behavior: Ajax** To enable animated page transitions, all
>   links that point to an external page (ex. products.html) will be
>   loaded via Ajax. To do this unobtrusively, the framework parses the
>   link's href to formulate an Ajax request (Hijax) and displays the
>   loading spinner. All this is done automatically by jQuery Mobile.

I believe that jQuery mobile does the AJAX request to the server, crops the `data-role="page"` item from the response, and replaces the current `data-role="page"` with it. That would explain why your JS code does not get executed when navigating but it does when refreshing.

> **Linking without Ajax** Links that point to other domains or that have
>   rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be
>   loaded with Ajax. Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh
>   with no animated transition.

Try to disable the AJAX navigation. It will cause a normal navigation.

Cheers.